# Is there an advantage of using a named function over an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I see IIFE's all the time.

I see a series of statements that are left open, i.e, they are not encapsulated by brackets.

Why have I not seen a function followed by its invocation

```
    // lib code...we are inside an IIFE 

    function fooName () {
    }
    fooName();

    // lib code...
```

to immediately invoke a series of statements when you don't need closure, i.e. you don't need persistent or static local variables?

Is there something wrong with this idiom/pattern?  Does it have name? Is it used?

**Non - "small" code**

```
function manageGlobal() {
    if (win.$A && win.$A.cg) {
        $A.extend($A, window.$A);
    } else if (window.$A) {
        $A_previous = window.$A;
    } else {
        $A = window.$A = {};
    }
}
manageGlobal();
```

Comment: Is there a `setTimeout()` inside the "fooName" function?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking me for clarification, so if you are, what I meant was that the pattern of function declaration followed by a call to the function is common when the function uses `setTimeout()` to cause itself to be executed again in the future. The initial function call is necessary to start the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a function declaration followed by its call.

It has no name as it has **no specificity** : it's just basic obvious use of the language.

By the way, it has no advantage over an IIFE :

- It's more verbose
- It adds a name to the global (or local) namespace.

If you don't need a closure, and don't need to avoid namespace polluting as you're in a small IIFE, then you may just directly include the code you have in your function instead of declaring it.

Comment: I think that the question may be about the definition and invocation of a function (a declared function) *inside* an IIFE.

Comment: @pure_code *Why* would you use this pattern ? If you don't need a name, why declare it ? You make your code more complicated with no gain.

Comment: @Pointy the reason why I hadn't see initialy the comment "inside an IIFE" is because it wasn't here before, just like in [OP's last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075098/why-isnt-this-pattern-idiom-used). BTW, pure_code, you're too often creating question and deleting them without comment just after the first answer. That's terribly rude for people answering.